# How to show the particular div based on the selected option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I select the option from the ddl ,the div of same class is not visible,so I want when I select the option from the ddl so the div of the particular option appear.

In my select, option value are coming from the  database (1.mobile,2.email), so I want when I select mobile then the div number 1 appear.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#theme').change(function() {
    $('#number' + $(this).val('mobile')).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<label for="mode">Communication Mode :</label>
<?php
      echo "<select name='ddlmode' id='theme' required >";
      echo "<option>-select-</option>";
      include "configpdo.php";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare( "select value from key_master where ems_key='k006' or ems_key='k007'" );
      $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
     foreach ( $result as $row ){
    echo "<option>" . $row[ "value" ] . "</option>";
                  }
      echo "</select>";
      ?>
  <div id="number1" class="box">
    <label for="sms">SMS text</label>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="number2" class="box">
    <label for="mail">Mail :/label>
      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea rows="2" cols="80"></textarea>
    <label for="email" style="font-size: 20px;">Body</label>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: you need to hide all `div[id^=number]` divs ids starts with `number` and show the section by using `option:selected` `index()` .. the next code should work with you

```js
$(function() {
  $('#theme').change(function() {
    $('div[id^=number]').hide();
    var GetSectionNum = $(this).find('option:selected').index() == 0 ? 1 : $(this).find('option:selected').index(); // if the selected option is 0 mean 'select' change it to the next of it directly .. so in this code if you try to select 'select' it will select mobile
   $(this).find('option:eq('+GetSectionNum+')').prop('selected' , true);
    $('#number' + GetSectionNum).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="theme">
   <option>Select</option>
   <option>Mobile</option>
   <option>Email</option>
</select>
<div id="number1" class="box">
  <label for="sms">SMS text</label>
  <textarea rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="number2" class="box">
  <label for="mail">Mail :/label>
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <textarea rows="2" cols="80"></textarea>
  <label for="email" style="font-size: 20px;">Body</label>
  <textarea rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: in this code,This_value == 'ddl',here ddl is what?

Comment: i give the property of the div is display none,not working

Comment: @ankur Manoj answer should work with you

Comment: @mohamed-yousef- i tried but the when i comment propert of div display none,after this if i select the option they hide the div but not show.

Comment: @ankur answer updated

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef-this code is working,but when i click email,they show the subject textarea but not showing body text area they only show the vertival single line if i use the nicedit formating in body.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `select` html is like this

```
<select>
   <option value="0">Select</option>
   <option value="1">Mobile</option>
   <option value="2">Email</option>
</select>
```

then try this

```
 $(function() {
    $('#theme').change(function() {
       $('.box').hide();
       $('#number' + $(this).val()).show();
    })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put value on options like this

```
echo "<option value="'.$row[ "value" ].'">" . $row[ "value" ] . "</option>";
```

hope it helps.